# Array access, pointer confusion

Tags: c, pointers

I have some inherited code and a function which takes a character array as a parameter.

```
typedef char myString[256];

void MyFunc(myString param)
{
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
  {
     if (param[i] ....
```

I would like to make this more efficient and pass a pointer to the char array:

```
void MyFunc(myString *param)
{
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
  {
     if (*param[i] <========= Thsi is wrong
```

When I try to reference the array elements, I get the wrong value, so obviously something is wrong with my pointer dereferencing. It has been a while since I coded in C, so I can't see the obvious mistake.

Can someone please point it out?

Comment: When passed to a functions, arrays "decay" to pointers anyway. You won't make it more efficient by playing games like that.

Comment: Time to study array semantics

Comment: This might be helpful material BTW: [The C Book - Arrays, the & operator and functions](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter5/arrays_and_address_of.html). One of my favourite C references.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably don't want to pass it via a pointer; when you use the type in the argument, it becomes a pointer anyway, and second level of indirection is less efficient.

If you do use the 'pointer to an array' notation, then you need parentheses to get the precedence correct:

```
if ((*param)[i] ...)
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

`myString *` is a pointer to a char array with 256 elements, i.e., `param` has type

```
char (*)[256]
```

so you have to dereference `param` first, then access its element.

1. By dereferencing param, you got the address of the first element of the array `param` points to.
2. `(*param)[i]` is then the ith element of the array in question.

Answer (score 1):

// This is OK: an array can be treated as "char *", and vice versa
    char myString[256];

```
void MyFunc(char * param)
{
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
  {
     if (param[i] ...
```

> Q: I would like to make this more efficient and pass a pointer to the
>   char array

A: There's absolutely *no difference* in efficiency whether you pass "param[]" or "*param"

```
for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
  {
     if (*param[i] <==== <========= Thsi is wrong
```

Yup - it's wrong.  Again, "`param[]`" and "`*param`" should be treated the same way.

Same with or without the "typedef", too :)

Finally, here's the same program with the typedef:

```
typedef char myString[256];

void MyFunc(myString param) 
// This is treated as "MyFunc(char param[256])" 
// It is *identical* to "MyFunc(char * param)"
{
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
  {
     if (param[i] ....
```

Comment: There is a difference, in both notation and efficiency, when the parameter to the function is `MyFunc(myString *param)` instead of just `MyFunc(myString param)`.

Answer (score 0):

use as below :

```
if (*(param +i) ...)
...
```